# Should I be using normpdf to answer this question?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

If the mean of a sample is 30, and the standard deviation is 10, then how would I evaluate a question that asks me how likely it is that I would obtain a value of $34$? Also the size of the sample is 20.

I'm confused about this:

Would I calculate $P(X=34)=P(Z=\frac{34-30}{8})=P(Z=0.5)$?

From this I'm confused because a cdf would give me $P(X\leq x )$ and I'm unclear on if I should use normpdf on a TI-84 calculator instead of normcdf.

I'm an AP Statistics student and my teacher says never to use normpdf for this class.

My second approach would be to see that $Z=\frac{34-30}{4} = 0.5$ so a value of 34 is only half a standard deviation above the mean. This would mean it's pretty likely.

Also, does the sample size matter in this situation?

Comment: "how likely it is that I would obtain a value of $34$?" is a slightly strange question for a continuous distribution such as the normal distribution; as the probability of exactly $34$ is zero, as it is for any other particular value.  But if you are sampling from a discrete distribution, the probability of a sample mean of $34$ may be more than $0$, even if the normal distribution is a reasonable approximation of the distribution of the sample mean.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to interpret this question.

In many cases, we are interested in the question "*how likely is it that we observe a value at least as extreme as X?*" This is often the case in hypothesis testing, where we will reject the null hypothesis if a value at least as extreme as a specified threshold is observed. So in this case, we might respond with either $\mathbb{P}(Z \geq 0.5)$ or $\mathbb{P}(|Z| \geq 0.5)$, which both measure how likely a value at least this extreme is observed.

Another way might respond is to answer the question "*how likely is it that we observe a value between $Z = 0.5 - \epsilon$ and $Z = 0.5 + \epsilon$?*" Here $\epsilon$ is some constant that specifies the length of the interval we're interested in (you can think about this as the error of a measurement). In this case, our answer would be
$$\Phi(0.5 + \epsilon) - \Phi(0.5 - \epsilon)$$
where $\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF.
Of course, answering this question would require a reasonable choice of $\epsilon$.

Comment: thank you but the question doesn't say "how likely is it that we observe a value at least as extreme as 34" so am i just supposed to interpret it this way or the second way you suggest? also what about my second approach which refers to how many standard deviations it is from the mean?

Comment: It's unclear - are you learning about hypothesis testing? If so, maybe the first one. But it's hard to say honestly because the question is vague. As for looking at the number of standard deviations from the mean, it's a good start, but unfortunately saying $0.5$ standard deviations is "pretty likely" isn't gonna really cut it.